# select2 select multiple itmes from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

```
var selectedValues = new Array();
selectedValues[0] = "1";
selectedValues[1] = "4";
$('#select2-multiple-employees').select2('val', selectedValues);
```

It selects only the first index in the array of selectedValues.
I'm using [select2](https://select2.org/) version: 4.0.8

Is there another way to do this? It doesn't work for me

Solution: 
Adding under insert selectedValues

```
$('#select2-multiple-employees').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are 2 excerpts from `select2` documentation:

> [**Configuration**](https://select2.org/configuration): To configure custom options when you initialize Select2, simply pass an object in your call to .select2()

- but you do not pass such object

> [**Basic Usage**](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage): The DOM cannot be safely manipulated until it is "ready". To make sure that your DOM is ready before the browser initializes the Select2 control, wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` block.

- but you do not wait for the page to be ready

i hope this will give you some lead.